# Query the Manager object from AD in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, active-directory

We're trying to set up a workflow for approval of an item in a list in Sharepoint 2010, where whenever a user creates an item in the list, it automatically routes to their manager for approval before being added to the queue of work items.  We'd also like to go a step further and recursively query up the heirarchy until we reach a user with a specific "Job Title".

We use the "manager" attribute and "title" attribute in user profiles so we should be able to poll all this info from AD.

Anyone have any experience or thought as in how to accomplish this task?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Are you having problems with a particular part? You're going to need a couple different parts... custom workflow and the code to query AD.

Comment: Well I'm kind of needing to know where to start really.  That info puts me on the right path though.

Comment: If the info is in AD then you should be mapping it to the users profile in SharePoint.  If this is the case then you can query the users SharePoint profile for manager/title (not sure about walking the management tree though).

Comment: All this information is already sync'd with sharepoint as well, I forgot to mention that.  Mysite has the proper organization chart as well.

Comment: Go ahead and read the information from user profiles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

+1 to what Patricker suggested with respect to user profile traversal. For AD Query assuming you are using an MS product for AD, create an [LDAP Query](http://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=ldap%20query%20basics&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CCUQFjAA&url=http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa996205%28v=exchg.65%29.aspx&ei=8v7WTqDhOIPprQfb4-X7DQ&usg=AFQjCNHwdHYFqmoDFxJWFpjULEj2pLe_8g&cad=rja).

You should be able to figure out lot of tools as well to build LDAP queries. My personal favorite is [Search Using Active Directory Users and Computers](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa996205%28EXCHG.65%29.aspx#DoingASearchUsingADUC)

To execute LDAP queries via .Net you would use classes in System.DirectoryService namespace